# Filtrar con Pipe en angular

Tags: angular

Hola estoy teniendo problemas para filtrar con pipe, hasta hace nada filtraba todo perfecto, pero le añadí un nuevo campo y no me filtra por el.

Estoy filtrando un objeto y un Array

El Array me lo filtra por todos los campos que le tengo puestos, sin embargo el objeto quiero filtrar por name_session y hora y solamente me lo filtra por hora. El campo hora como se llama igual que el del array uso el mismo pipe para filtrarlo.

Este es mi Pipe:

```
    transform(items:any,filterHora:string,filterOtros:string,auxTerapeuta:string,auxPaciente:string,filterFecha:string,filterSesion:string){
        if (items && items.length){
            return items.filter(item =>{
                if (filterHora && item.hora.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterHora.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }
                if (filterOtros && item.otros.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterOtros.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }
                if (auxTerapeuta && item.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(auxTerapeuta.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }
                if (auxPaciente && item.nombre_paciente_search.toLowerCase().indexOf(auxPaciente.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                  return false;
                }
                if (filterFecha && item.fecha.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterFecha.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                  return false;
                }
                if (filterSesion && item.name_session.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterSesion.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                  return false;
                }

                return true;
           })
        }
        else{
            return items;
        }

    }
}
```

Ahora pos pongo el campo input

```
<div class="col-md-6 campos" *ngIf="tipo == 1">
        <label>Nombre de la sesión</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="filterSesion" [(ngModel)]="filterSesion" placeholder="Nombre de la sesión">
                {{filterSesion}}
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 campos">
        <label>Hora</label>
        <input type="time" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filterHora">
</div>
```

Por ahora si que me filtra, pero sin embargo por nombre sesión no me filtra, no hace nada es más me tira un error cuando comienzo a escribir, tengo un campo para filtrar por otros en mi Array (Que me filtra perfectamente) ahora bien os dejo el error que me tira.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este sería mi For donde muestro los datos del objeto

```
<div class="citas-pacientes" *ngFor="let sesiones of sesion | filter:filterHora:filterSesion">
        <div class="row" id="list-pacientes-events">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                {{sesiones.nombre_grupo}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {{sesiones.name_session}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                {{sesiones.fecha}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                {{sesiones.hora}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {{sesiones.nombre_terapeuta}}
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme podido explicar bien, muchas gracias!

Comment: Si usas el mismo pipe para filtrar los dos arrays que se ven en las capturas, tendrás que comprobar que los campos existen: El primero no tiene `nombre` ni `otros`

Comment: Necesito entonces otro pipe?